# Theming WSO2 4.x.x - extracting .jar to directory no longer works

Tags: wso2, theming

All the documentation that I have found on re-theming WSO2 products suggest unzipping the corresponding .jar file and putting it in a directory with the same name while updating the theme.

It seems like this is no longer possible. Carbon 4.x either refuses to start or, if a patch is pending, fails due the fact that the expected .jar file is now a directory.

Either way this does not seem to work.

What is the preferred way to achieve this with the latest version of WSO2 products?

Regards,
 Stefan

*previous documentation*

- http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2010/11/customize-ui-theming-wso2-carbon-based-products
- http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/11/playing-around-carbon-product-themes
- http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/12/retheming-carbon-products

Answer (score 0):

When creating the directory with the same name as the jar, did you use the - or the _. For example was it carbon.ui_4.x.jar or carbon.ui-4.x.jar. If it was the - (dash) can you try with the _.

Comment: Results in 
java.io.IOException: Destination '/var/www/wso2/wso2bam-2.3.0/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.bam.styles_2.3.0.jar' exists but is a directory

or

SEVERE: Context [/] startup failed due to previous errors (if changed from _ to -)